# How can i remove the hotmail email was linked to my local administrator?

Tags: windows, windows-10

When i installed my windows 10 i went directly to cmd (Run as Administrator) then type this command:

```
net user Administrator /active:yes
```

after this i logout from my current user and login to Administrator account and delete the old account.

after a while i don't know how my brother link his email to my Local Administrator account!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qIQM.png)

How can i remove this and back my local administrator to the original status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the solution.

open regedit.exe and delete the key for the (email) account you want to remove from the following location: HKEY_USERS.DEFAULT\Software\Microsoft\IdentityCRL\StoredIdentities

It worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

open regedit.exe and delete the key for the (email) account you want to remove from the following location: HKEY_USERS.DEFAULT\Software\Microsoft\IdentityCRL\StoredIdentities

Found the solution here:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/remove-microsoft-account-from-my-local-account-in/c2a24e44-91d9-4758-ae11-379ea406bfaa?page=2

After restart my PC i went to my setting then i seen the remove button of the MS email and all thing back to normal status!

Thanks.